# Fresh installation exit code 127

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

Just freshly created project with PhpStorm for composer for laravel. I filled DB info to .env and ran migrations now i followed tutorial, to get laravel-backpack running and it fails at second command:

> php artisan backpack:base:install

It starts but then throws following:

> In Install.php line 94:
>                                                                          The command "composer require backpack/generators --dev" failed.
>                                                                          Exit Code: 127(Command not found)

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: IS not it temporary ?

Comment: Looks like the installer is trying to run composer, is composer installed in your path?

Comment: I can tun composer normally in terminal, so i guess composer is working

Answer (score 0):

You need to require backpack first bevor you can run the artisan command.

```
composer require backpack/base
```

Now you should be able to install it.

```
php artisan backpack:base:install
```